# Exact time between 2 DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-2.0

I would like to know many minutes between 2 dates?

Example : Now - tommorow at the exact time would return me 1440.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

int diff = dt2.Subtract(dt1).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: He said tommorow, not yesterday :)

Answer (score 7):

Look at the TimeSpan class.

```
        DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        TimeSpan diff = date2.Subtract(date1);
        Console.WriteLine(diff.Minutes);
```

Comment: Vendetta downvoting is funny.

Comment: If it weren't for your rep, I'd say "Welcome to SO!" ;)

Comment: Lol...Hi to another Seattilite

Comment: Console.WriteLine(diff.Minutes); should be Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalMinutes) ;)

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tommorowTime = currentTime.AddDays(1);
TimeSpan diffTime = tommorowTime - currentTime ;
Console.WriteLine(diffTime.TotalMinutes);
```