# Get the days of year and all the hours between 2 dates in C#

Tags: c#

I have folder structures like Year (2016)->day of year (308,309) -> hour in the day (00 to 23). I want to know how to get all the days and hours between 2 dates say between today 9am and yesterday 10am. Is there an easy way to do this?

My bad! I didn't give enough information. So I did try Span before I asked this and I don't want to get the different like the span.days, hours or mins instead i want the days of the year and hours between 2 dates.

like between yesterday 10 am and today it will 307th day 10th hour,11th hour and so on... until today 308th day and 9th hour. I can do this by looping thru the dates but i wanted to know if there is a straight forward way.

Comment: Take 2 dates of the examples and try it out.

Comment: What have u tried so far??

Comment: Please start with showing some effort in solving it... Then show us where you are stuck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exact time between 2 DateTime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210607/exact-time-between-2-datetime)

Comment: When you say… _“I have folder structures like”_. File names like: 2016-308-10, 2016-309-08?  It is unclear whether you are trying to get the all the hours between two dates or gather files such that the file name is within the two dates. Those are two completely different things.

Comment: The folders are like 2016 and then a 308 subfolder inside 2016 and a 08 subfolder inside 308.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a simple class for storing the data you need:

```
class DateInfo
{
    public string Year {get;set;} 
    public string DayOfYear{get;set;}
    public string Hour {get;set;}
}
```

and then get the results:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).AddHours(10);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(9);
IList<DateInfo> dates = new List<DateInfo>();

while (d1 <= d2)
{
    DateInfo dateInfo = new DateInfo()
    {
        Year = d1.ToString("yyyy"),
        DayOfYear = d1.DayOfYear.ToString(),
        Hour = d1.ToString("HH"),
    };
    dates.Add(dateInfo);
    d1 = d1.AddHours(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually providing some answer rather than marking it as duplicate without even reading the whole question. I am doing some stress testing using this because I will have folders, subfolders like this for 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

There would be n number of ways to find out the difference between two dates. 2 of them are as follows

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2016, 11, 03, 10, 00, 00); 
DateTime b = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(b.Subtract(a).TotalHours);
```

This will give you the total hours between two dates Where as

```
TimeSpan span = (b - a);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds));
```

This will give you the details in the format which everyone can understand.

Comment: @Avenger789: If I understand your question. You can choose the first date of the year as your `a` like `DateTime a = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);` and it would give you the expected output using span. And for yesterday date n time you again need to assign the value to `b` and do the same calc.

Comment: No it wont. It will still give me the difference and not enumerate the values between those. I will need all the hours/days/year between the dates enumerated